# Spring Security Access Denied page with multiple security configs

Tags: spring-security

I have two security config in my application one for the UI and one for the rest API

I would like to add an access denied page to the UI but not for the rest api.

For the first configuration I have:

```
.antMatchers("/gui/**")
                    .hasAuthority(accessRight)
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/gui/error")
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .userInfoEndpoint(createUserInfoEndpointCustomizer())
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
```

For the second

```
.antMatchers("/api/**")
                    .hasAuthority(accessRight)
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .userInfoEndpoint(createUserInfoEndpointCustomizer())
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
```

I would expect the access denied page to be returned only on the first case but it seems like I receive it in case I am trying to access the api as well.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a `DelegatingAccessDeniedHandler` that holds multiple instances of `AccessDeniedHandler`s, one for UI and one for REST API and decides which internal instance to invoke basis 'Accept' header or requeste URL.